# AVQueuePlayer stream status?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I really new to Obj-C and iOS development, i found very much useful information here, but here is a question I didn't find the answer.

I got instance of `AVQueuePlayer` which plays audio stream from url.

How can I know that audio stream is loaded? For example when I press "Play" button, there is couple of seconds delay between a button press and actual start of streaming. 
I looked at developer.apple.com library and didn't find any method that I can use to check status of `AVQueuePlayer`. There is one in `AVPLayer`, but `AVPlayer` is not supporting stream over http as far as i know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you mean by "loaded": do you mean when the item is fully loaded or when the item is ready to play?

`AVQueuePlayer` supports http streams (HTTP Live and files) in the same way as `AVPlayer`.  You should review the [AVFoundation Programming Guide, Handling Different Types of Asset](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/02_Playback.html).

The most common case is when an item is ready to play, so I'll answer that one.  If you are working with iOS with `AVQueuePlayer` < 4.3, you need to check the status of `AVPlayerItem` by observing the value of the `AVPlayerItem` status key:

```
static int LoadingItemContext = 1;

- (void)loadExampleItem
{
    NSURL *remoteURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://media.example.com/file.mp3"];
    AVPlayerItem *item = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:remoteURL];
    // insert the new item at the end
    if (item) {
        [self registerAVItemObserver:item];
        if ([self.player canInsertItem:item afterItem:nil]) {
            [self.player insertItem:item afterItem:nil];
            // now observe item.status for when it is ready to play
        }
    }
}

- (void)registerAVItemObserver:(AVPlayerItem *)playerItem
{
  [playerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:(void*)&LoadingItemContext];
}

- (void)removeAVItemObserver:(AVPlayerItem *)playerItem
{
  @try {
    [playerItem removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status"];
  }
  @catch (...) { }
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
if (context == &LoadingItemContext) {
        AVPlayerItem *item = (AVPlayerItem*)object;
        AVPlayerItemStatus status = item.status;
        if (status == AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay) {
            // now you know you can set your player to play, update your UI...
        }   else if (status == AVPlayerItemStatusFailed) {
            // handle error here, i.e., skip to next item
        }
    }   
}
```

That is just a pre-4.3 example.  After 4.3 you can load a remote file (or HTTP Live playlist) using the code example in [AVFoundation Programming Guide, Preparing an Asset For Use](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/01_UsingAssets.html), with `loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:completionHandler`.  If you are using `loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys` for a HTTP Live stream you should observe the @"tracks" property.